# Drop box values not reflecting in Access 2003 database

Tags: ms-access

I have created a CRM with access 2003. I have addedd 1 drop box with some values which is reflecting on the from with all the selection. However when i select the option in drop box while adding a new record all info populates in the database expect the value selected in the drop box. Kindly help??????????????????

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your ComboBox's Control source is set and the the Bound Column is set to the column with the values you want to store in the table.